# is there an alternative for X_SUB_MSISDN?

Tags: php, android

this code return number of your sim card, works fine with http request and returns MSISDN, but when you request with https protocol doesn't return any number.

Comment: <?php echo @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_SUB_MSISDN']?>

Comment: `this code` can't see any code.

Comment: also how does your question relate to `android`?

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to detect visitor's MSISDN -

```
public function getMSISDN()
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID']))
    {
        # Mostly this Server Vars Attribute all mobile phones
        $msisdn = trim($_SERVER['HTTP_X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID']);
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTS_CLID']))
    {
        # Mostly this Server Vars Attribute is for Nokia and SonyEricsson
        $msisdn = trim($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HTS_CLID']);
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_MSISDN']))
    {
        # Mostly this Server Vars Attribute is for Motorola and Siemens
        $msisdn = trim($_SERVER['HTTP_MSISDN']);
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['X_MSISDN']))
    {
        # Mostly this Server Vars Attribute is for Motorola and Siemens
        $msisdn = trim($_SERVER['X_MSISDN']);
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['X-MSISDN']))
    {
        # Mostly this Server Vars Attribute is for Motorola and Siemens
        $msisdn = trim($_SERVER['X-MSISDN']);
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_NETWORK_CLIENT_MSISDN']))
    {
        # Mostly this Server Vars Attribute is for Motorola and Siemens
        $msisdn = trim($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_NETWORK_CLIENT_MSISDN']);
    }
    else
    {
        $msisdn = $_COOKIE['User-Identity-Forward-msisdn'];
    }

    if( $msisdn == '' )
    {
        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        # $msisdn = $headers['x-msisdn'] ? $headers['x-msisdn'] : exit;
        $msisdn = $headers['x-msisdn'];
    }

    return $msisdn;
}
```